# Accessibility of test coverage reports for blind people

Tags: java, accessibility, code-coverage

I am currently helping a member of my team to get in grip with our new project and the tools we are using. We use Java as a primary language. A particularity of my colleague is that he is blind. He's working primarily with Emacs, and he runs maven targets in a terminal.

After I'm done implementing, I find it very useful to check my test coverage. I'd like my colleague to be able to check coverage as well. I have two ways of getting this information:

- Use IntelliJ integrated test coverage (it uses EMMA and shows a green, red or yellow color next to each line). Very convenient, as I can see this information immediatly after having run the tests, with no further interaction

  This won't work for my colleague as he can't use IntelliJ, and it would probably not work anyway as there is no textual representation of the coverage info
- Use Cobertura reports. They use the same concept of *line in green/red*  They are fine for macro information like overall coverage in a class, but not for checking which line has not been covered.
  Actually he could dig into the HTML sources of the report and find out which one has class `nbHitsUncovered`, but it seems very impractical.

I would really like to show him how to get his coverage data quickly. Does anybody know of a tool that shows coverage without relying on colors? Or do we have to write our own? (by transforming the HTML report, for instance)

Comment: sonar can show code coverage, don't know if it can be read easier than the cobertura reports: http://www.sonarsource.org/sonar-to-manage-unit-tests-and-improve-code-coverage/

Comment: @Antoine. I removed my answer about using FitNesse. Sorry, but I didn't answer your question about code coverage.

Comment: @oers Thanks. We already have Sonar set up on our project. I never run it locally, though, but I could give it a try. Sonar is a topic I wanted to bring up with my co-worker anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m a totally blind developer who does my work on Windows with the Jaws for Windows screen reader so this won’t map exactly to the developer you work with. With a little programming it looks like cobertura test results are the easiest to deal with. Based on the following sample XML report it shouldn’t be difficult to throw together a quick Perl script to check for lines with a hit count of 0.
https://raw.github.com/jenkinsci/cobertura-plugin/master/src/test/resources/hudson/plugins/cobertura/coverage-with-data.xml
I was able to find out that line 24 was the only one executed 0 times with a quick find for

```
Hits="0"
```

Although I was able to find out what line wasn’t executed I had to scroll up quite a bit to figure out what class and method the line was located in. A quick Perl script could eliminate the need to scroll back and provide the package, class, and method the line is located in more efficiently.
I took a look at a sample Emma HTML report using Google Chrome and it was pretty accessible. I could tell what methods were fully tested and what weren’t. Figuring out what lines were executed and what ones weren’t was more difficult. I could tell a method wasn’t 100% executed and would then navigate to it in the report. I then had to use the keystroke provided by my screen reader to announce color on each line of code. I forget the exact color names but I could tell the lines that were and weren’t executed since my screen reader listed them as having different colors. This worked but was slow since I had to manually check each line of a method; that wasn’t completely executed since my screen reader can’t automatically announce color changes. I’m not sure how your developer would do the equivalent since I don’t know his exact assistive technology setup.

Comment: My colleague is using Jaws on Windows for browsing the web as well, but using the XML output of Cobertura seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Great stuff. The work has been done for us! Perhaps an XSLT will help you display the XML data in more accessible format.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a dig around Antoine as I also use SONAR and Cobertura on my projects and am intrigued by your problem. From what I can see when you tell the ANT task to generate "html" as the output you get all the line information that want, but as you've pointed out it's not an easily parseable format (and possibly subject to change).

With SONAR I tell Cobertura to output "xml" which gives me a file named `coverage.xml` with the output. Unfortunately it does not include line-by-line data and I cannot see any [ANT task parameters](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html) to include it from the Cobertura docs.

It makes sense to me that the file named `cobertura.ser` contains all of the data you require, but only the HTML report displays it for you. I believe the answer to your question may lie in trying to extract the required serialised data from cobertura.ser.

Looking at the source code I can see the following classes

```
net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.html.HTMLReport
net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.xml.XMLReport
```

What I suspect you can try and do is take a copy of the HTMLReport as a base and try writing the same output as XML which you can then parse for your own purposes (or mjust ad the same method calls used by HTMLReport in XMLReport). I can see the string `nbHitsUncovered` in `HTMLReport` so hopefully you only have one class to write.

I've googled around and can't see anyone having done this, but it looks like a useful enhancement.

Comment: the cobertura.ser file is not human readable. You have to run a report to make sense of it. But XML is available if you tell format="xml". See: http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/introduction.html

Comment: I don't have Cobertura installed but the sample XML I found online gives a hit count for each line. If the XML I found is valid then a hit count of 0 should provide all the information you need.

Comment: @oers. Yes link to the [ANT task parameters](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html) provided in the answer explains the options for "xml" and "html" report output. See section titled "cobertura-report Task"

Answer (score 0):

How about using a GreaseMonkey script that searches all the lines having the class nbHitsUncovered and adds some list/table containing the information wanted to the report?